# FLUTTER: How to listen to Firestore's Collections changes ? ( Document Creation / Deletion )

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I use STREAMBUILDER in Flutter to update my App according to documents values changes inside my Firestore Database Collections. Everything works perfectly and my App's UI gets updated accordingly to Documents values changes.

But now, I also need to DETECT when:

- a DOCUMENT got DELETED inside my Collection
- a NEW DOCUMENT is CREATED inside my Collection

Does FIREBASE / FIRESTORE emit a specific STREAM / EVENT in such cases, that i can listen with my STREAMBUILDER ?

Comment: Did you mean [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)(Cloud Firestore triggers)?

Comment: I'm reading that, thanks for the link. So, if I understand right, I can't do anything without writing server side code with Javascript ? Does this mean I must create some server backend code that will be triggered and send notifications to my App when those events are occurring ? I was hoping there was a way to do it client-side with DART / FLUTTER, listening to some Firestore's event streams. It seemed impossibile to me that i'm succesfully listening to DOCUMENTS' VALUES CHANGES (without writing a single line of server code) while there isn't a way to listen to DOCUMENT CREATION / DELETION...